# Is interleaving used in MIMO?

Tags: antenna, communication, wireless, wifi, digital-communications

Correct me if I'm wrong, this is my understanding of MIMO:

[image]

Is this how MIMO is able to increase data rate?

Comment: I've updated my answer to your previous question to expand my unshielded cable analogy, and to hint at some of the techniques involved, still very much a the simplified level.

Comment: @Neil_UK I've seen it. Thanks for such a comprehensive answer. But I think the mathematics of matrix only explains how the channels are separated. I still don't understand how data rate is increased. Anyway, thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Once you know that the channels can be separated, it's obvious that you have more carrying capacity than you had before. How the incoming data is split between those parallel channels is a matter for design. Note that the incoming data is not a serial stream of 100 Mbit/s, that diagram is an oversimplification. Telephony deals with *circuit switching*, where you connect a serial stream of 100 Mbit/s. Internet protocol deals with packet switching, where you throw packets of data at a link, fast enough to get your video throughput. MIMO uses internet protocol.

Comment: That means the answer to your question, how does MIMO increase the date rate, is, it doesn't. It increases the data throughput. Data rate is a circuit/telephony concept, where 100 Mbit/s has meaning. Data throughput is a network concept, where you want to know how long it takes to transfer a file, or how much buffering you need to stream video when the aggregate data rate is twice what is needed for the video's bit rate, but is bursty.

Comment: But how does MIMO, being a physical layer concept, know which information is to be sent to which channel?

Comment: It doesn't, because it doesn't need to. MIMO doesn't know about 'channels'. That's the joy of the layered model, and network/packet switching. MIMO provides a physical service to the layers above, of shifting labelled packets of data. It's the responsibility of the upper layers to know what channels those packets belong to (how to label them), or what order they should be in, or whether in the event of transmission failure whether that packet should be retransmitted, or dropped. As engineers, we only work on one layer at a time, because our heads would explode if we tried to span several.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colouring of those data bits is figurative. It's far, far more complicated than that. That diagram is what's known known as a [Lie to Children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children). It's the sort of diagram that would be shown in a presentation to politicians when trying to get them to license spectrum to your organisation.

- Does each parallel data stream carry some of the data?

Yes

- Is the data stream taken apart in some way before sending out on the MIMO streams and then reassembled afterwards?

Yes

- Is the mean data rate on each parallel stream lower than the mean data rate on the original and recovered streams?

Yes

- Does MIMO take 1 bit at a time and multiplex them strictly between the four streams?

Absolutely not.

I fell foul of a lie to children when I was a child. My shape-sorter I used when I was pre-school had nice regular polygonal prisms to bash through holes, a square, a circle and a regular triangle. Later on in my maths lessons, I insisted that a triangle had three angles of 60°. I was convinced I was right, I'd seen it in my shape sorter. I would not believe the teachers who told me that a triangle could have different angles. I even had stand up arguments with them in class, at the age of perhaps 8. It inhibited my learning geometry.

Those one bit per channel pictures are the nice easy 60° angles of a kid's shape-sorter. But we have isosceles triangles, right triangles and scalene triangles, which correspond to the several layers of message encoding, packing, [forward error correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_correction_code#Forward_error_correction), [HARQ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_automatic_repeat_request) processing, matrixing that is not shown on this diagram, and which certainly does not work one bit at a time, which the word 'interleaving' seems to imply. These work in blocks or chunks of data. That is needed to ensure correct message transmission over a medium that isn't 4 channels for 4 antenna at the best of times, varies, and is unreliable. With 4 antennae you might get approaching 4 streams in a lab environment, 3 is good for out in the field, and you can generally expect more than 1.

Looking at your diagram, one of the lies is that the red antenna sends a signal to the red receiver and so on. That's the same sort of level of incorrect as the input stream being taken a bit at a time to each channel. Each TX antenna sends signals to all the RX antennae. The data is matrixed onto all the transmit streams, and is deconvolved at the receive end. The logically distinct channels are created mathematically from the different views of the single channel that each antenna has. See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/540786/how-does-mimo-increase-data-rate) Q&A for a bit more detail on how the RF channel is handled to create multiple logical channels.

Comment: We call those kinds of diagrams "lightning diagrams", and they show in one form or another in presentations given to upper management.

Comment: @SteveSh I think OP drew this themselves to illustrate what they've understood so far

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Neil's excellent answer:

No, that figure is not correct. In quite a few ways. I think you need better literature!

---

First of all: This is **totally** the opposite of how MIMO works:

[image: NOOO!]

If you had four parallel transmissions that don't interfere with each other, as your parallel lightning bolts indicate, there'd be no need for MIMO: you'd simply had four parallel streams of data, as if you had, say, 4 fiberoptic cables.

**This is not the case.** All the transmissions from the transmitter's antennas add up at **each** receiver antenna. Every receiver antenna sees a *mixture* of the different transmit antenna signals.

But: Each of these TX antenna Nr. n -> RX antenna Nr. m has a different attenuation and phase (a different channel coefficient).

We hence consider the MIMO channel as a matrix with as \$N_{TX}\times N_{RX}\$ complex entries.

---

You have *one* MIMO matrix on the transmitter, and *one* at the receiver, not one per antenna. That makes no sense; you need multiple antennas to even build a vector that you'd multiply with the matrix.

---

There's no interleaving/deinterleaving (serializer/deserializer). You take a vector of symbols in the transmitter, consider everything a vector space, do a base transform, transmit the same vector represented to that different base, then the channel multiplies that transmit vector with the MIMO channel matrix explained above. Then, it's the receiver's job to invert **the product of TX matrix and channel matrix** (not just invert the TX matrix).

The result is something that converts the "mushes up all the different transmit signals" channel to a channel that *looks* like parallel ("synthetic") channels, only different in the amount of noise they see (simply because not all physical paths are equally strong, there mathematically can't be a case where all resulting channels are equally strong in general).

---

You don't transmit bits, you transmit complex symbols. Depicting this as 0101... is misleading at best, and labeling the streams in Mbps is wrong.

You actually shouldn't put a fixed data rate at each stream, because that's not what MIMO does, either. Due to different "synthetic" channels SNR, you'll get lower mutual information, and thus data rate, on some of them. Whether or not your system respects that or just assumes that all used channels are equally bad is a design question, but assuming that all channels carry the same data rate contradicts the mathematical model.